# how can i change the output of JavaScript to go to directly to another page instead of an alert window?

Tags: php, javascript

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <title>Validate Zip Code</title>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function IsValidZipCode(zip) {
                    var isValid = /20132/.test(zip);
                    if (isValid)
                        alert('Valid ZipCode');
                    else {
                        alert('yep')
                         }
                }
            </script>
        </head>


   <body>
    <form>
    <input id="txtZip" name="zip" type="text" /><br />
    <input id="Button1" type="submit" value="Check My Zipcode"
    onclick="IsValidZipCode(this.form.zip.value)" />
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I need to use this to allow the user to go either to a page that says sorry we cannot service your area or to another page that says yes we can service your area based on wheter their zipcode is listed.

also how can i add more than one zip code in the isValid = line?

Comment: How you will check the zipcode? from database or manually?

Comment: manually against a short list i create

Answer (score 1):

Setting `window.location.href = "your url here";` answers the first part of your question.

> *"also how can i add more than one zip code in the isValid = line?"*

If you want to stick with a regex test you can use the regex or `|`:

```
var isValid = /^(20132|20133|20200|90210|etc)$/.test(zip);
```

Note that I've also added `^` and `$` to match the beginning and end of the entered string - the way you had it you'd also get matches if the user entered a longer string containing that code, e.g., `"abc20132xyz"` would match.

I'd be more inclined to do this validation server-side though.

Comment: the output of the javascript now just apends "/ziptst.html?zip=20132" onto the existing url. checkout www.stoneybrookfarm.org/ziptst.html

Comment: That's probably because you are using a submit button, so the default form submit is taking place which causes the current page to reload. Try `<input type="button">` instead of `<input type="submit">`.

Comment: also how would you recomend going server side with this?

Comment: To do it server side, if the intention is to redirect to some other page either way you could just remove the JS altogether and add an `action="someURL.php"` to your form element (and stick with the submit button). Then in the PHP code validate the ZIP as required and do a server-side redirect (sorry, I'm not a PHP guy so I couldn't tell you exactly how to code that with PHP but it should be fairly simple).

Comment: changing to the "button fixed it" i will look into doing it via php on the server side

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isValid)
    document.location.href="validzipcode.html";
else {
    document.location.href="yep.html";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function IsValidZipCode(zip) {
    var isValid = /20132/.test(zip);
    if (isValid)
        document.location.href="valid_zip.html";
    else {
        document.location.href="not_valid_zip.html";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function IsValidZipCode(zip) {
                var isValid = /20132/.test(zip);
                if (isValid)
                  window.location = baseurl."/valid.php"
                else {
                    window.location = baseurl."/invalid.php"
                     }
            }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect it in javascript with following code , that can be put in your example instead of alert()

```
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try ajax for this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <title>Validate Zip Code</title>



<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
//Browser Support Code
function IsValidZipCode(zip){

    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

        //alert(ajaxRequest);
    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){


        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            //var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
            //ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
                        alert(ajaxRequest.responseText);
                        if(ajaxRequest.responseText=="")
                        {
                                alert("sorry we cannot service your area");
                        }
                        else{
                                window.location = "Page.php?zip="+zip+"";
                        }

        }
    }
    //var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
    //var wpm = document.getElementById('wpm').value;
    //var sex = document.getElementById('sex').value;

    var queryString = "?zip=" + zip;

    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "zip_check.php" + queryString, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}

//-->
</script>



        </head>


   <body>
    <form name="form1" method="post">
    <input id="txtZip" name="zip" type="text" /><br />
    <input type="button" id="Button1"  value="Check My Zipcode"
    onclick="IsValidZipCode(document.form1.zip.value)" />
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: what would be the benifit of using ajax